# Table of content: how to remove the page number of subsection in LaTex?

Tags: table-of-contents

Could anybody help me to remove the subsection of page number?
Just want

[image]

to be like this

[image]

Thank you very much.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\date{} % Leave date blank 
\pagestyle{myheadings}   
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.05in,right=1.05in]{geometry} 

\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft} 
\usepackage{titletoc}  
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}   
\titlecontents{section}[0ex]  
              {\addvspace{-0.4ex}\filright}  
              {\contentspush{\thecontentslabel\ \  }} 
              {}{\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[14pt]   
              {\addvspace{-0.8ex}\filright \small}   
              {\contentspush{\thecontentslabel\ \ }} 
              {\empty}{\titlerule*[-0ex]{.}\contentspage}   

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titlespacing{\section}{0ex}{*1.1}{*0}   
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0ex}{*0.8}{*0}   
\titleformat*{\section}{\large \bfseries}  
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize \bfseries}   

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}  


\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents

\section{Three levels}
Computer vision

\section{Dating back}
\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The spacing is quite horrible. Why do you squeeze all the lines in the toc so together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply change

```
\titlecontents{subsection}[14pt]   
              {\addvspace{-0.8ex}\filright \small}   
              {\contentspush{\thecontentslabel\ \ }} 
              {\empty}{\titlerule*[-0ex]{.}\contentspage}
```

to

```
\titlecontents{subsection}[14pt]
              {\addvspace{-0.8ex}\filright \small}
              {\contentspush{\thecontentslabel\ \ }}
              {}{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\date{} % Leave date blank
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.05in,right=1.05in]{geometry}

\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\titlecontents{section}[0ex]
              {\addvspace{-0.4ex}\filright}
              {\contentspush{\thecontentslabel\ \  }}
              {}{\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[14pt]
              {\addvspace{-0.8ex}\filright \small}
              {\contentspush{\thecontentslabel\ \ }}
              {}{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0ex}{*1.1}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0ex}{*0.8}{*0}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large \bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize \bfseries}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Three levels}
Computer vision

\section{Dating back}
\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Note, however, that a better result can be obtained using `tocloft` instead of `titlesec` using these settings:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{3pt plus.2pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\date{} % Leave date blank
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.05in,right=1.05in]{geometry}

\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{3pt plus.2pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0ex}{*1.1}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0ex}{*0.8}{*0}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large \bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize \bfseries}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Three levels}
Computer vision

\section{Dating back}
\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It's great and working well! Thank you very much

Comment: @Hyden You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved, if you want. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)